# Basics of battery charging and discharging

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, batteries

I am trying to understand batteries.

1) If I have a rechargable battery of 1.2 V 1000mAh, it means I can draw 1A at 1.2 V for one hour and the battery is said to be discharged ? Does "discharged" mean 0 volts and so I can't draw anymore current from it ?

2) Can I recharge this battery by simply applying a constant voltage of 1.2 V across it terminals ? Or it should be charged by some constant current ?

3) Can the battery be considered fully charged, right when its voltage reaches 1.2 V ?

4) What differentiates a non-ideal battery from ideal battery in these cases ?

I don't know whether there is a generic theoretical answer to these. If there is, it would be helpful.

Comment: This is a big topic in itself and I think you'll get much further researching this on the interweb.

Comment: Hmm I tried but was confusing. So I summed up some doubts I got. Are there any simple answers ?  Don't want to get too deep though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you misunderstand the purpose of the site, Meenie. It's for electronics design. It's not an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to people on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. It is a 'deep' and involved topic you've chosen, sorry. Welcome and have a read of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: A great resource is http://batteryuniversity.com for these questions.  Check out the sections on charging different battery chemistries.

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva557/snva557.pdf <--- A Good document from TI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does "discharged" mean 0 volts and so I can't draw anymore current
>   from it ?

You need to read the data sheet for the battery i.e. something like [this](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/hr20-2500_eu.pdf) should pop-up: -

[image]

This is for a 2500 mAh battery of terminal voltage 1.2 volts and the data sheet tells you that the "end-voltage" is 1 volt. In other words from full-capacity to end-capacity the voltage has fallen from 1.2 volts to 1 volt. It also states that this assumes a constant 500 mA discharge.

So, you need to read and understand the data sheet.

> Can I recharge this battery by simply applying a constant voltage of
>   1.2 V across it terminals ? Or it should be charged by some constant current ?

You need to read the data sheet and take advice from it.

> Is the battery considered to be fully charged when its voltage reaches
>   1.2 V ?

Normally, yes but under a prescribed load.

> What differentiates a non-ideal battery from ideal battery in these
>   cases ?

The voltage into an open circuit does not really tell you much about the state of charge but, as a battery discharges, the internal series resistance increases hence the terminal voltage reduces with time when under loading conditions.

Comment: Can we draw current when voltage drops to 1 V ?

Comment: Suppose battery is at 1 V now and I am charging it. Can I say the battery is fully charged right at the moment the voltage reaches 1.2 V ? Or there are other parameters which is to be taken into consideration ?

Comment: For the battery I have linked, it will operate down to 0.9 volts but you are on the slippery slope of rapidly running out of stored energy and you should certainly not discharge some batteries past their lower voltage limit (as stated in their data sheet).

Comment: For all these questions you MUST read the data sheet to get specific answers.

Comment: Hmm I am new to this topic ...I thought a generic answer is there.

Comment: There are possibly as many answers are there are [battery technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_types).

Comment: I did not know that the internal resistance of a battery increases with discharging. Seems like batteries are complex things. Thank u for the guidance. I will look into it. :-)

Comment: @MeenieLeis no problem.